# PHP Like/Unlike button with jquery

Tags: php, jquery

i was following a tutorial on youtube to make a simple Like/unlike button for my status system, i got most of it done, but it will not UPDATE my likes and not INSERT the like into the database, please help me say whats wrong, i tried so much now..

**Function to get status:**

```
 function getStatus($conn) {
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM status ORDER BY sid DESC";
       $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
       while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
           echo "<div class='post'>".$row['message']."<br>";

                $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM status_like WHERE uid=1 and sid=".$row['sid']."");
                if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
                    echo "<span><a href='' class='unlike' id='".$row['sid']."'>unlike</a></span>";
                } else {
                    echo "<span><a href='' class='like' id='".$row['sid']."'>like</a></span></div>";
                }
                }


       }
```

**jquery code**

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.like').click(function(){
                    var sid = $(this).attr('id');
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'test.php',
                        type: 'post',
                        async: false,
                        data: {
                            'liked': 1,
                            'sid': sid

                        },
                        success:function(){

                        }
                    });
                });
            });
          </script>
```

**and the last php code where i think the problem is:**

```
if (isset($_POST['liked'])) {
        $sid = $_POST['sid'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM status WHERE sid=$sid";
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        $n = $row['likes'];
        $uid = 1;

        $sql2 = "UPDATE status SET likes=$n+1 WHERE sid=$sid";
        $sql3 = "INSERT INTO status_like (uid, sid, username) VALUES (1, '$sid', '$uid')";
        mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
        mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);
        exit();


    }
```

Comment: set alert in click function.. and echo in if (isset($_POST['liked'])) {
} and tell me

Comment: okey i added alert('test'); inside the click function and i get the alert up when i click on the "like button" but i still dont understand where to put the echo. @vSugumar

Comment: Inside if. Also Turn on error reporting in problem code and code network tab and click on response

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: @tadman can you please explain this better for me? where did i do something bad? and how should i do it? :)

Comment: The safest way to write queries is with single quotes, like `'INSERT INTO x (a, b) VALUES (?, ?)'` so that way there's no string interpolation. That forces you to use placeholders like `?` to represent your data, any mistakes insert literal `$var` values in your database. It's a bug, but a harmless one. With double-quoted strings you run the risk of very real, very nasty SQL injection holes opening up.

Comment: So what should i do whith the values i have single quotes arround then? Like i had: "INSERT INTO status_like (sid, uid, username) VALUES ('$sid', '$uid', '$name')"; and i should change the double quotes (") with single quotes (') ? and then what should i do where i had single quotes? like arroung $sid, $uid and $name? :) @tadman

Comment: There's several links in the original comment that explain. I also included an example in the previous comment. It's literally a `?` in place of your data and `bind_param` does the substitution for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (isset($_POST['liked'])) {
        $sid = $_POST['sid'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM status WHERE sid=$sid";
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        //$n = $row['likes']; // your code            
        $n = (int) $row['likes']; // try like this.. might be likes in string so convert to int
        $uid = 1;

        //$sql2 = "UPDATE status SET likes=$n+1 WHERE sid=$sid"; // Your code

        // Do like this `status` in query because status is reserved keyword of MySql for more details you could visit this link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html
        $sql2 = "UPDATE `status` SET likes=$n+1 WHERE sid=$sid";
        $sql3 = "INSERT INTO status_like (uid, sid, username) VALUES (1, '$sid', '$uid')";
        mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
        mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);
        exit();


    }
```